# Call Codebehind From javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, client-side, onkeypress

I wanna a problem,

Trying this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function txtOnKeyPress(txt1) {
        if (txt1 != 'undefined') {
            var txt2 = document.getElemejavantById('<%=TxtArama.ClientID %>');
            txt2.value = txt1.value;
            <% Session["Sercert"] = TxtArama.Text;%> 
            //alert(txt2.value);
            var DTT =<%= GetSearcher("") %>;
            alert(DTT);

        }
    }
    <%--function CallCodeBehindMethod() {
        var txt2 = document.getElementById('<%=TxtArama.ClientID %>');
        alert(window.PageMethods.GetName(txt2));
        //this.GetName(txt2);
    }--%>
</script>
```

JS is client side textbox keypress event

And

code behind event is

```
protected string GetSearcher(String KeyValue)
    {
        KeyValue = Session["Sercert"].ToString();
        String aa = "";
        if (KeyValue.Length > 0)
        {
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            DT = DbClass.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName LIKE '%" + KeyValue + "%' LIMIT 10", "MySql");

            for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                aa += "<a href=\"" +ReWriterPath(DT.Rows[i]["ProductId"].ToString(), DT.Rows[i]["ProductName"].ToString()) +"\">" +DT.Rows[i]["ProductName"] +"</a><br />";
            }


            RptSearcher.DataSource = DT;
            RptSearcher.DataBind();
            UPLSearcher.Update();
        }
        return aa;

    }
```

I try fill data in repeater this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPLSearcher" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LtrSearcher"></asp:Literal>
                                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptSearcher">
                                                <ItemTemplate>

                                                    <a href="<%# ReWriterPath(Eval("ProductId").ToString(), Eval("ProductName").ToString()) %>"><%# Eval("ProductName") %></a><br />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:Repeater>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I wanna update my repeater in search keypress event on code behind method.
And reupdate my update panel and list in results.
But js code and method running only page load. and key pres not run on code behind side code.
But this //alert(txt2.value); run every time keypress.

please help.

Comment: You Need To Write Web Method to call Codebehind Function...

Comment: What about using ajax ?

Comment: What is `document.getElemejavantById` ? (typo, i guess :) )

Comment: im fix it wrong :) document.getElemejavantById 
but try again and fail :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create [WebMethod] in code behind. than you can call that method from javascript.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function txtOnKeyPress(txt1) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/yourpage.aspx/GetSearcher",
            data: '', // put your data here that you want to pass in server method
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        //write your code what you want to display on success
    }
</script>
```

Create your code behind method

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod()]
    public static string GetSearcher(String KeyValue)
    {  //Your code goes here  }
```